# Method for proving $ f^{-1}(G \cup H) = f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H) $

Tags: functions, proof-writing, proof-verification

Prove that if $ f: A \rightarrow B $ and $ G,H $ are subsets of $ B $, then $ f^{-1}(G \cup H) = f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H) $.

My (incorrect) Attempt:  Suppose $ x \in f^{-1}(G\cup H) $.  Then there exists a $ y \in G \cup H $ such that $ f^{-1}(y)=x $.  Since $ y \in G \cup H $, $ y\in G $ or $ y \in H $.  Without loss of generality, suppose $ y \in G $.  Then $ x \in f^{-1}(G) $.  So $ x \in f^{-1}(G) \cup f^{-1}(H) $.

Assume $ x \in f^{-1}(G) \cup f^{-1}(H) $.  Then $ x\in f^{-1}(G) $ or $ x\in f^{-1}(H) $.  Without loss of generality, suppose that $ x\in f^{-1}(G) $.  So there exists some $ y \in G $ such that $ f^{-1}(y)   = x $.  Since $ y \in G $, $ G \cup H $.  Thus $ x \in f^{-1}(G \cup H) $. QED

It has been a while since I last did proofs for inverse functions, and I recall that my initial way of doing them back in day was wrong.  Does this method work?  Thanks

Comment: Seems legit.${}$

Comment: Before solving an exercise you should be able to check the definitions of the involved operations. You haven't used the definition of $f^{-1}$ (or rather you have used a wrong one which only makes sense when $f$ is bijective).

Comment: You want to rewrite this so that you have $f(x) = y$ instead of $f^{-1}(y) = x$.  Also in the second paragraph you have $f^{-1}(G) = x$, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Absolutely Correct. That's exactly how one proves it. You can draw vein diagrams and make your self believe that what you proved is actually correct.

Comment: My book defines the inverse function $f^{-1}(H) $ of $A$ as $f^{-1}(H)= \{ x \in A : f(x) \in H \}  $.

Comment: Two comments say that the proof is correct. But nothing in this "proof" is correct.

Comment: I am not confident in my answer being correct (and I suspect it isn't because it isn't the most common way of approaching this sort of proof); however, the disagreement suggests it is at least usefully illustrative (ie of how to or not to do things).  I'll edit my OP to avoid misleading people once we get to the bottom of this.

Comment: The core assumption that I seem to be making is that if $x \in f^{-1}(H)$, then there exists a $y \in H$ such that $f^{-1}(y)=x$.  If this assumption is false, it would follow that there exists an $ x \in f^{-1}(H)$ such that there is no corresponding $y $. 

I understand that the function would have to be surjective for every element of $ B $ to be mapped onto.  However, isn't the inverse function solely concerned with $ x $ such that a mapping does exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is not an evaluation of your proof, but an alternative one.  For clarity I'll be using a slightly different notation: $\;f^{-1}[Y]\;$ instead of $\;f^{-1}(Y)\;$.)

Let's start at the most complex side, here the right hand side, and see if we can use the definitions to find out which elements $\;x\;$ are in this set:
\begin{align}
& x \in f^{-1}[G] \cup f^{-1}[H] \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;``\text{definition of $\;\cup\;$"} \\
& x \in f^{-1}[G] \;\lor\; x \in f^{-1}[H] \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;``\text{basic property $(0)$, see below, twice"} \\
& f(x) \in G \;\lor\; f(x) \in H \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;``\text{reintroduce $\;\cup\;$ using its definition -- really the only thing we can do"} \\
& f(x) \in G \cup H \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;``\text{reintroduce $\;\cdot^{-1}[\cdot]\;$ using basic property $(0)$"} \\
& x \in f^{-1}[G \cup H] \\
\end{align}
By set extensionality, this proves the original statement.

The basic property of $\;\cdot^{-1}[\cdot]\;$ used here is
$$
(0) \;\;\; x \in f^{-1}[Y] \;\equiv\; f(x) \in Y
$$

Comment: I think my mistake was that if $f$ isn't one-to-one, then reversing the function will yield multiple answers for a single value of $y$.  Thus, $x $ defined in this fashion could be multiple elements.  It would have been more complicated this way, but if I had clarified that it was an element of, but not necessarily all of $f^{-1}(y)$, then perhaps the proof would have been correct, although overly lengthy compared to your normal one.  

I am still not sure why Martin thought my method assumed bijectivity, as I don't get why it assumed surjectivity.

Comment: @Dargatz: You simply didn't use the definitions, therefore the proof was wrong. What is $f^{-1}(y)$ by the way? Do you mean the fiber $f^{-1}(\{y\})$?